# What is the message key for "The target Installation directory is not empty" in install4j

Tags: install4j

Install4j:
I want to override the default error message when user selects a already existing installation directory. The default message is "The target Installation directory is not empty", I couldn't find the message or a equivalent key in "$INSTALL4J_HOME/resource/messages/messages_*.utf8".
I have read through the guide http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The message for that condition is actually

```
DirExists=The directory:\n\n{0}\n\nalready exists. Would you like to
          install to that directory anyway?
```

Maybe you have customized it already in the custom localization file.